# Indexing a multidimensional numpy array with another multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a multidimensional array, say:

```
x = np.random.randn(2,3,4,4)
x.shape
(2, 3, 4, 4)
```

Then I have an array, which contains a chosen index in the second dimension for all elements, say:

```
y = np.random.randint(3, size=2*4*4).reshape(2,4,4)
y.shape
(2, 4, 4)
```

I want to get an output array that contains all elements of `x`, apart from the second dimension, where it would have just one value specified by an index in `y`. So, the output array `z` would also have the shape of `(2, 4, 4)`. How can I accomplish this using indexing? I've already tried all combinations of indexing with ellipsis and `y`, and moving around the dimensions of `x`.